# opengl c++ code doesn't give expected result

Tags: c++, opengl

```
 **//My 3D vertex data class**
class Vertex   
{   
public:    
    Vertex(float xx, float yy, float zz) : x(xx), y(yy), z(zz) { }    
    virtual ~Vertex() {}    

private:    
    float x;   
    float y;   
    float z;    
};

**//My quad data.** 
std::vector<Vertex> quadVertexData;    
quadVertexData.push_back(Vertex(-0.5,  0.5, 0.0));     
quadVertexData.push_back(Vertex(-0.5, -0.5, 0.0));   
quadVertexData.push_back(Vertex( 0.5, -0.5, 0.0));     
quadVertexData.push_back(Vertex( 0.5,  0.5, 0.0));
```

**//This is how I make my render call.**

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &_vao);
glBindVertexArray(_vao);
glGenBuffers(1, &_vbo);
glGenBuffers(1, &_ebo);


void render(std::vector<Vertex>& vertices, std::vector<unsigned int> indices)
{
 glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vbo);    
 glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertex) * vertices.size(),  
 &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);     //tried with sizeof(vertices[0]) too.
 glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _ebo);       
 glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned int) * indices.size(),  
 &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);    
 glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);     
 glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);       
 glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);     
 glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);     
}
```

**ISSUE** : //Instead of quad, I get an unexpected triangle as show in pic.
How should I pass `bufferdata` to get desired results?
Same code if I tried with **`glm::vec3`** then its works fine.

**//Snapshots :**

With My Vertex class
[image]

With glm::vec3 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I also tried hardcoding 12 and still the result was same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Vertex   
{   
public:    
    Vertex(float xx, float yy, float zz) : x(xx), y(yy), z(zz) { }    
    virtual ~Vertex() {}    
private:    
    float x;   
    float y;   
    float z;    
};
```

`sizeof(Vertex)`is not 12 as you expected. It is probably 16 or 24 (depends on 32 or 64 bit system). This is because you have an `virtual` destructor. This causes that somewhere in the object has to be stored the pointer to the virtual function table. Finally the vertex coordinates in `std::vector<Vertex> quadVertexData` are not tightly packed.

To do what you want, you should use a `struct`

```
struct Vertex   
{   
    float x;   
    float y;   
    float z;    
};
```

Of course your code will work if you omit the `virtual` keyword in `class Vertex`:

```
class Vertex   
{   
public:    
    Vertex(float xx, float yy, float zz) : x(xx), y(yy), z(zz) { }    
    ~Vertex() {}    
private:    
    float x;   
    float y;   
    float z;    
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to address the problem causing issue. It works as expected after omitting the virtual keyword. ...I displayed the size with virtual keyword and it shows 16 and after omitting 12 :).

Comment: Oh!..Sorry for that, It was my first post here, don't know much how it work here yet.. but will explore soon. Thanks Rabbid76.